# Does the banker in Chemin de Fer have to memorize this table?

Tags: untagged

I read a description of Chemin de Fer which said that if the punter takes a third card, then the banker "must" react according to the following table:

[image]

It would seem to be non-trivial to memorize this table and obviously the other bettors could get angry at me if I did not make the expected play. Is it really required to memorize this table to play Chemin de Fer?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this casino description of the game's rules](https://www.casino-games-online.biz/cards/chemin-de-fer.html):

> #### Bank Handling in Chemin de Fer

> The player sitting on the right side of the croupier, who is based in middle of the table, is first to be the Banker. ... The players take turns in the role of the Banker.

> ...

> #### A Choice

> .... There is no need to worry about the rules of Chemin de Fer – they are watched carefully by the croupier.

The above makes no mention of aids at all, only that the croupier will ensure errors in procedure are corrected; so presumably one may possess and refer to memory aids in regards the rules as needed.

Further there is no requirement, either by the Rules or strategic considerations, for the Banker's dealt cards to remain hidden once the Player has announced to Stand or Draw. A Banker may thus freely turn them over after that Player decision is made, either for assistance on the Rules
or to demonstrate compliance with them.

That said however; redrawing the chart above as follows gives a much simpler rule for the Banker to follow:

Except for the combinations 9-3 and 4-5, the Banker must Draw when the Player's third card is:

- equal or greater to twice his initial hand value less 6; and
- less than or equal to 7.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't appear to actually reach the point of definitively answering the question, which is whether the banker must memorise the table. It appears to go in that direction but it leaves concluding the answer as an exercise for the reader. This answer should instead conclude with a firm answer itself.

Comment: @doppelgreener From what I see in the question there is no indication that the banker or anyone else can't refer to the rules or other reference data during play and can only depend on their memory.

Comment: @JoeW All I'm suggesting is the answer should give a clear confirmation in the affirmative or negative on whether anyone's expected to memorise the table. I can synthesize what I think the conclusion might be, but I'm not an expert capable of answering the question, so I don't necessarily have confidence my interpretation would be correct.

Comment: @doppelgreener I understand what you are saying now

Comment: @doppelgreener: The table is much easier to learn when reorganized as I have edited to show.

Comment: @ForgetIwaseverhere But is it necessary to memorise it? There's a _yes_ or _no_ here, or a _probably_ or a _probably not_, and I'm not sure whether it is or isn't necessary from reading this answer.

Comment: @doppelgreener: Better now?

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no requirements in the rules to memorize that chart and it does not appear to be expected at any point in time. You can refer back to the rules  or make a cheat sheet of your own design for this.

If you look online there are other formats of when you draw or don't draw that could make it easier to understand. A good example can be found with these [rules](https://www.casino-games-online.biz/cards/chemin-de-fer.html).

[image: Draw Rules]

Comment: Believe it or not this domain doesn't load for me at all. (It does appear to work—[it's just me](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/casino-games-online.biz?proto=https&www=1)—but maybe my ISP blocks it because of that domain name and/or TLD (`*.biz` has always been a hotbed of scammy websites). Is there an alternative source available to reference? (I don't mean to hassle, just noticed it.)

Comment: @doppelgreener Added a screen shot from the page with the draw rules